# SQL Injection: How to defeat ANSI SQL mode (escape single quote with two)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm playing on a practice site and trying to defeat a site that uses ANSI SQL mode (escapes single quotes ' with '' (two single ticks)) on the password field. My goal is to login. I already know the username as it was given.

I've tried numerous combinations in the password field such as the following. I think I have to use some variant of the backslash \ but I've been confused for quite a while. I would appreciate some help, thanks!

```
\'or'1'='1
```

Comment: Time to read up on the principles at work here, and look at how [testing tools](http://sqlmap.org) deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

If it is exploitable, you'll have to figure out the appropriate escape character that the application layer will ignore, but the database will not.

There are a few options:

```
\'  This is a single escaped quote, that presents as a literal instead of a transalation.
''  This is another way of escaping quotes, depending on the sql generator,
though since you have an engine that doubles quotes, this would end up being ''''
\'' A literal quote escape quote is sometimes necessary to get through more than one layer of abstraction
\\' May pass on a double quote with the escaped \ generating an odd number of quotes
```

Sometimes the validation parsers are vulnerable to certain characters because they use regex or literal finders, but don't account for differing types of characters, so you can pick something that the parser won't continue with, but doesn't break SQL

```
\t \n Playing around with spaces that might not be recognized might allow 
you to hide your attack string from the quote doubler.
-- /**/  These are sql comments that could disrupt the validator.
```

Some SQL parsers will translate Unicode, html code, hex, or other character formats into ASCII for execution, these work on a surprising and unfortunate number of SQL servers.

```
U+02BC is a apostrophe modifier that can translate to a simple apostrophe
U+0027 is the Unicode for an apostrophe
&#39; is the html code for an apostrophe.
```

There are a number of different unicode/html/hex values that could potentially be translated to escape or single quote characters, this is because many characters don't map back to ASCII and the translator doesn't always do a good job.

So, the best thing to do is to try to get back an error message with a bad sql string and then build back out from there.  You don't need to start with a SQL attack directly, errors tell you quite a bit about what you're dealing with. 
 If you can determine a version through any type of error, even if it isn't an escape, you might be able to get a SQL error that prints the version, for which you can look up a vulnerability.  Sometimes extremely long lines of ASCII text can also cause this problem.

Comment: So I'm playing around with it but I can't seem to get a valid mysql query going.   Say I have SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE '[INPUT]'. So to defeat this table that uses double quotes I'm thinking of putting in \'or 1=1 which translates to SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE '\'' or 1=1, but I need to somehow put 1=1 in literals under the condition that single quotes are doubled

Comment: Did you first find a Unicode/Hex/escape character that causes an error?  Once you've found a value that you can slip past the parsing validater, to cause an error, this is how you start building up the injection attack.  If the Unicode translation works then it would be U+0027 or 1=1 --